# Let $n=3^{1000}+1$. Is n prime?

Tags: number-theory, congruences

Let $n=3^{1000}+1$. Is n prime?

My working so far:

$n=3^{1000}+1 \cong 1 \mod 3$

I notice that n is of form; $n=3^n+1$

Seeking advice tips, and methods on progressing this.

Comment: Advice tip: $n$ is an even number larger than $2$, how could it possibly be prime???

Comment: Please explain why

Comment: [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Is+3%5E1000+%2B1+a+prime+number%3F) says no.

Comment: Because $3^k$ is an odd number for every natural $k$, and $1$ is obviously an odd number, and the sum of two odd numbers is even.

Comment: Note: $3$ is odd, $3^2$ is odd times odd so it's also odd. $3^3$ is thus also odd, all the way to $3^{1000}$. Odd + 1 is even.

Comment: Side note:  writing $n=3^n+1$ is unusually bad notation.

Comment: @lulu: Yes, I didn't get that far reading this question (stopped pretty much right after the title).

Comment: @barakmanos  Very understandable.

Comment: How do you show $3^k$ is odd for every natural $k$?

Comment: @unseen_rider, see my answer. Just replace $1000$ with $k$ and it will still be valid. Completely elementary approach could be this: can product of two odd numbers be even?

Comment: @unseen_rider See [Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic). An integer $n\ge 2$ is even if and only if its unique prime factorization includes $2$. In this case, $3^k$ has the unique prime factorization $3^k$ (notice $3$ is prime), which doesn't include $2$, so $3^k$ is odd.

Answer (score 4):

Since we have

$$3\equiv 1 \pmod 2 \implies 3^{1000} \equiv 1 \pmod 2 \implies 3^{1000}+1\equiv 0\pmod 2$$

$3^{1000}+1$ is not a prime.

Comment: How did you go from $3 \cong  1 \mod 2 $ to $3^{1000}\cong 1  mod  2$ ?

Comment: Well if $x\equiv a \pmod n$ and $y\equiv b\pmod n$, then $xy\equiv ab\pmod n$. This is easily proved if you are interested, @unseen_rider.

Answer (score 0):

Taking binomial expansion,

\begin{align}
3^{1000}+1&=(2+1)^{1000}+1\\
&=1+\sum_{k=0}^{1000}{1000\choose k}2^k1^{1000-k}\\
&=1+{1000\choose 0}+\sum_{k=1}^{1000}{1000\choose k}2^k\\
&=2\left[1+\sum_{k=1}^{1000}{1000\choose k}2^{k-1}\right]
\end{align}

So $3^{1000}+1$ is composite.